# Capturing Images from Webcam Using OpenCV , Django and show the captured image in HTML Page

Tags: python-3.x, django, opencv, django-views, django-templates

I want to capture the image using OpenCV in Django web application and show captured image in HTML page and needed to compare the captured image with the previously detected images.

can anyone give me idea how to code ?

Comment: Check if this article is of any help. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/11/creating-a-face-detection-api-with-python-and-opencv-in-just-5-minutes/

Comment: And this. https://learnopencv.com/turn-your-opencv-code-into-a-web-api-in-under-10-minutes-part-1/